# How to calculate font size from Illustrator to CSS?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, units

I got following Illustration from Grapics Designer:

[image]

The font size what I am curious about is 7pt in Illustrator. How can I calculate the "web font size" of it? I have a MacBook Pro, its width is 1440px, the artwork in Illustrator is 571px.

So I though I can calculate like:

7pt = 9.29px

9.29px * 1440 / 571 = 23.42

But it is just way bigger then I expected:

[image]

Comment: If that’s 7pt text in the Illustrator screenshot, I’m guessing you’re not zoomed out to 100% view. If you’re viewing the Illustrator document at, say, 175% zoom, as a starting point, try making the CSS font (7 x 1.75 =) 12.25pt = 16.3px. See if that fits; otherwise adjust until it does.

Answer (score 0):

It is a designer's job to simplify and decide on what looks best. If you're a programmer and just received this from a designer, take the initiative and adjust until it looks right.

If 23.42px is too big, just try 18 or 16px, don't get stuck on rigid conversion formulas.

Also, Illustrator comes from a pre-web background, so most of the methods and units are not made to apply for web code directly. That's why people use XD, Figma and/or Sketch now, because these apps are 100% built and optimized to generate web assets, units and numbers.

Comment: 8 or 9px would be **way** too small. That’s barely legible. The current conversion makes it 23.42pt, which is too big, but not by a factor of 300%.

Comment: It's not my job to know what's big or not in the particular situation, the OP mentioned 9.29px being too big. I was just making a point of rounding the value to a number which looks not big, not small, just right. Adjust "by eye".

Comment: No he didn’t. He said that 9.29px * (1440 / 571) = 23.42px was too large. He said nothing about 9.29px, except as an intermediate value. If you look at text on a webpage in size 9.29px, it’ll be tiny. The default browser size is 12pt = 16px.

Comment: Yeah ok i missed that part where he converts by screen ratio. Regardless, my point remains valid.